# What are some books that have works of mathematicians?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I am looking for a book that have important works of mathematicians before 21st century. I am not looking for any particular mathematician but it will be nice if the matter is arranged in topic wise format, like all great works in algebra etc. I am not looking for historical or philosophical books but the original works, edited to suit modern symbols and language.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: There are some sourcebooks, perhaps some that have translations and modern notation, not sure http://bookstore.ams.org/hmath-10/

Answer (score 2):

You could try "God Created the Integers: The Mathematical Breakthroughs That Changed History" by Stephen Hawking. I think it fits your description accurately, except maybe (IIRC) the modern notation part.

Comment: What do you mean by IIRC? Anyways the book looks really amazing thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @JonathanRichardLombardy "IIRC" means "If I recall correctly".

Answer (score 0):

You could try and own a book that talks about Ramanujan's lost notebook. The finders of the book laid out the assertions he made in context with contemporary mathematics. This book is the 8th listed [here](http://bayesianthink.blogspot.com/2012/12/the-best-books-to-learn-probability.html).